# Pandas: sum of every N columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
ID   2016-01   2016-02 ...  2017-01  2017-02 ... 2017-10  2017-11  2017-12
111    12        34           0        12          3        0        0
222    0         32           5         5          0        0        0
```

I need to count every 12 columns and get

```
ID   2016   2017
111   46     15
222   32     10
```

I try to use

```
(df.groupby((np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 31) + 1, axis=1).sum().add_prefix('s'))
```

But it returns to all columns
But when I try to use

```
df.groupby['ID']((np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 31) + 1, axis=1).sum().add_prefix('s'))
```

It returns

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of all columns without dates:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
```

**1.** `groupby` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)ed columns and selected first:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('-').str[0], axis=1).sum()
```

**2.** `lambda` function for split:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('-')[0], axis=1).sum()
```

**3.** converted columns to datetimes and `groupby` years:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df = df.groupby(df.columns.year, axis=1).sum()
```

**4.** `resample` by `years`:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df = df.resample('A', axis=1).sum()
df.columns = df.columns.year
```

---

```
print (df)
     2016  2017
ID             
111    46    15
222    32    10
```

Answer (score 2):

The above code has a slight syntax error and throws the following error:

> ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type

Basically, the groupby condition needs to be wrapped by `[]`. So I'm rewriting the code correctly for convenience:

```
new_df = df.groupby([[i//n for i in range(0,m)]], axis = 1).sum()
```

where `n` is the number of columns you want to group together and `m` is the total number of columns being grouped. You have to rename the columns after that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing the labels, you can try this:

`new_df = df.groupby([i//n for i in range(0,m)], axis = 1).sum()`

where n is the number of columns you want to group together and m is the total number of columns being grouped. You have to rename the columns after that.