# Calculate the average of several columns and insert it in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

[image: pic]

So right now, I have 96 time column (per day). Instead of having 96 columns (every 15 minutes), I want to have 24 columns (every 1 hour). Therefore I want to calculate the average of 00:00    00:15   00:30   00:45 for every row and put it into a new column 00:00. (and of course the same for the other 23 hours). Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: sum of every N columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607027/pandas-sum-of-every-n-columns)

Comment: Try looking at [How to Calculate the Average of Selected Columns in Pandas](https://www.statology.org/pandas-average-selected-columns/).

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). Ideally, provide a [mre] including complete example data and desired output (e.g. give us, say, 2 hours worth of 2 rows and the result you'd want). For specifics: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Like, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? Are you aware you can `groupby` on columns? Maybe resample would work too?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a data frame constructor so I can't test this code. But you would want to take your current data frame and stack it. That moves the time into the left. Then, within row groups, use `df.resample` while passing a 1 hour [time string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).

This might look something like this:

```
# df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)  # if needed
ndf = df.stack() \
    .groupby(level=0).resample(level=1, rule='H') \
    .mean()
```

This would convert a sample data frame like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     '00:15': [1, 2],
...     '00:30': [3, 4],
...     '00:45': [5, 6],
...     '01:00': [7, 8],
... })
>>> df
   00:15  00:30  00:45  01:00
0      1      3      5      7
1      2      4      6      8
```

Into:

```
>>> df.stack().groupby(level=0).resample(level=1, rule='H').mean()
0  2023-08-23 00:00:00    3.0
   2023-08-23 01:00:00    7.0
1  2023-08-23 00:00:00    4.0
   2023-08-23 01:00:00    8.0
dtype: float64
```

I would not store my data in this format where the time is the column. It isn't [Tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

This solution keeps the rows as individual units of observations with the `groupby`. You might want also to clean up the time. Pandas will store the time as *date-time* only. I think that issue is outside scope.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had forgotten to look back in here, thanks for your help guys.
My solution looks like this now:

```
time_columns = [f"{str(i).zfill(2)}:{str(j).zfill(2)}" for i in range(24) for j in range(0, 60, 15)]

df_copy = newdf.copy()

include_columns = [col for col in newdf.columns if col in time_columns]
filtered_df = df_copy[include_columns]

hours = [col.split(':')[0] for col in filtered_df.columns]
filtered_df.columns = hours

hourly_df = filtered_df.groupby(filtered_df.columns, axis=1).mean()

hourly_df.columns = [str(i).zfill(2) + ':00' for i in range(24)]
```